# Fast way of finding diverging terms in a huge expressions

Tags: performance-tuning

I have a huge expression called exp1 which is a function of rr. There are some terms in the huge expression which diverge when I put rr equal to zero. I want to find these terms. Does any one know an efficient way to do that?

exp1 is [here](https://files.fm/u/xp3mjfej#_)

For example, if

```
exp1=0.5/rr^2+ b/rr+c rr^3 + f rr^2;
```

I want to find `0.5/rr^2+b/rr;`

I know some ways to find these terms, but exp1 is very huge and I can not use simple ways like `Series[exp1,{rr,0,0}]`.

Finding nondivergencing terms also helps me (f rr^2 + c rr^3+... )

Comment: As is, the question is much to vague. Do you have a concrete example?

Comment: Yes. I ve just added it. @HenrikSchumacher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will give you some idea how to approach this problem.

A number of the assignments in your large file are not used. I hope this doesn't mean that the moment you get an answer that you will say you actually wanted something different.

You said that exp1 is the focus of your problem. exp1 is a simple numerator/denominator. I extract each of those and reorganize their form. This

```
Collect[Numerator[exp1], rr]/Collect[Denominator[exp1], rr]
```

very quickly returns a result where I then manually replace large expressions with corresponding simple variable names n6, n8, n9, n11, n12, n14, d6 and d12 just to be able to show and explain the structure of your problem in a compact form.

```
(-rr^6 n6-rr^8 n8-rr^9 n9-rr^11 n11-rr^12 n12-rr^14 n14)/(rr^6 d6+rr^12 d12)
```

Note that denominator is the only place in exp1 where rr appears in any denominator.

For each of the terms in the numerator that have rr to a greater power than 6, and assuming there isn't catastrophic cancellation, the numerator will go to zero faster than the denominator. That only leaves the `rr^6` to consider.

To look at this behaves as rr tends to zero I'll take a `Limit` using my substituted variable names instead of the original large expressions.

```
Limit[(-rr^6 n6-rr^8 n8-rr^9 n9-rr^11 n11-rr^12 n12-rr^14 n14)/(rr^6 d6+rr^12 d12),rr->0]
```

which very quickly returns

```
-n6/d6
```

If it helps, an alternate way of writing that fraction is

```
(-n6 - rr^2 n8 - rr^3 n9 - rr^5 n11 - rr^6 n12 - rr^8 n14)/(d6 + rr^6 d12)
```

You can automate putting exp1 into this form using

```
newexp1 = Collect[Numerator[exp1], rr]/Collect[Denominator[exp1], rr] /. rr^n_ :> rr^(n-6)
```

I believe this result might imply that if your large expression were suitably arranged that terms in your your fraction do not blow up as rr goes to zero, but instead go to zero because the powers of rr in the numerator are greater than the powers in the denominator thus leaving that relatively simple fraction.

You haven't said what it is that you want to do after you were able to extract the terms which blow up when you replace rr with zero, but perhaps this can give you some idea that you might be able to use.

Hopefully at least this might let you see that your problem might be considerably simpler than it originally seemed to be.

Please check all this very carefully for correctness before you depend on it.

Comment: Nice answer! TNX

Answer (score 4):

This attempts to compute a truncated Laurent expansion of the expression at `rr == 0`:

```
Series[0.5/rr^2 + b/rr + c rr^3 + f rr^2, {rr, 0, -1}]
```

> $\frac{0.5}{\text{rr}^2}+\frac{b}{\text{rr}}+O\left(\text{rr}^0\right)$

`-1` stands for the highest order of `rr` in the expansion, i.e. $\frac{1}{rr}$.

Comment: The problem is that, exp1 is very huge and I can not use this code. Please look at the exp1 in the link and my explanations

Comment: Can you explain a bit what a negative order means and why it works here?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean *"terms"* as in addends or summands, and making a simple example, given that you didn't share any examples of your own...

```
expr = FullSimplify@Sum[c[k] x^(k - 4), {k, 7}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Select[ List @@ ExpandAll[expr], (Abs[# /. x -> 0] == Infinity) &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now that you did share an expresion

```
exp1=0.5/rr^2+ b/rr+c rr^3 + f rr^2;

Select[
 List @@ ExpandAll[exp1], (Abs[# /. rr -> 0] == Infinity) &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I did share the exp1.

Comment: This method take lots of time, as exp1 is very huge

Comment: Performance goals nor examples of the expressions were part of the original question. It's very annoying when people [move the goalpost](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397). Anyhow, everything will take a long time in a huge expression.

Comment: Please note that it was mentioned in the original question that, exp1 is very huge.

Comment: I've just tried to make the question more clear. I didn't changed it

Comment: Yes, it really does. I am looking for a method to reduce this long time

Answer (score 1):

Your `exp1` is built up in steps, e.g.:

```
a = rhs1;
b = rhs2;
c = rhs3;

exp1 = f[a, b, c];
```

I suggest using [`Series`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series) for each definition:

```
a = Series[rhs1, {t, 0, 5}];
b = Series[rhs2, {t, 0, 5}];
c = Series[rhs3, {t, 0, 5}];

exp1 = Series[f[a, b, c], {t, 0, 5}]
```

For example, doing this for `AA1`, `AA2`, `AA3`, `AA5`, `AA6`, `AA7` yielded the series expression for `AA4` in a reasonable amount of time, and I expect it might work for your full `exp1` expression.